# Converting LINQ to lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I have this linq query, which is working fine, but I want to make it simple by using a lambda expression. Any suggestions or examples might help.

```
List<string> myList= (from d in entities.PERSONS_TABEL
                              where d.PERSON_ID == personFrom.PERSON_UNIQ_ID
                              select d.PERSON_NAME).ToList();
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What is `personFrom` ?

Comment: The code that you have is already using a lambda expression.  So you're already done.  Congratulations.

Comment: @maniak1982 person from is name of entity

Answer (score 2):

You perfectly can surround it as a lambda to reuse it, but it will be the same as a function:

```
var GetList = (Person personFrom) => {

    return (from d in entities.PERSONS_TABEL
                          where d.PERSON_ID == personFrom.PERSON_UNIQ_ID
                          select d.PERSON_NAME).ToList();

};
```

then anywhere else you can call it like this:

```
var myList = GetList(thePerson);
```

But as I said, is exacly the same as if you did:

```
public List<string> GetList(Person PersonFrom)
{
    return (from d in entities.PERSONS_TABEL
                          where d.PERSON_ID == personFrom.PERSON_UNIQ_ID
                          select d.PERSON_NAME).ToList();
}
```

If you're not passing it as a paramter to a function, a direct function call will be always better than a call to a lambda through a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, you've almost done it yourself already.

```
var myList = entities.PERSONS_TABEL
    .Where(p => p.PERSON_ID == personFrom.PERSON_UNIQ_ID)
    .Select(p => p.PERSON_NAME)
    .ToList()
```

"p" in front of the '=>' is the same as your 'from d' part, where p = d.
In other words, left from the '=>' lambda operator you put the input parameter(s) and right you put the statement or assignment block.

[More info about lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)